# Pandas: Creating column by adding 1 to the repeated elements, minus the 1st element that it finds when it is not consecutive, Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm developing the following code in Python using Pandas:

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    data = {"Value": [4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 7, 0, 4, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 7, 0, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3],
            "IdPar": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 22, 22, 28, 28, 28, 28, 0, 0, 38, 38 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    df['Count'] = df.groupby('IdPar')['IdPar'].cumcount() + 1
    df.loc [df['IdPar'] == 0, 'Count'] = 0
    df['Substract'] = df.index - df['Count'] ## Paint the subtraction, but it should not include the first repeated element
```

I want to achieve the following output, **which is the Final column, so that the result of this is the addition of 1 in each repeated element in the Substract variable, but after the first value found in the column, as long as the previous value in the row is not consecutive**:

```
        Value  IdPar  Count  Substract  Final
    0       4      0      0          0     0
    1       4      0      0          1     1
    2       2      0      0          2     2
    3       1      0      0          3     3
    4       1      0      0          4     4
    5       1      0      0          5     5
    6       0     10      1          5     6
    7       7     10      2          5     6
    8       0     10      3          5     6
    9       4     10      4          5     6
    10      1     10      5          5     6
    11      1      0      0         11    11
    12      3      0      0         12    12
    13      0     22      1         12    13
    14      3     22      2         12    13
    15      0     28      1         14    14
    16      7     28      2         14    14
    17      0     28      3         14    14
    18      4     28      4         14    14
    19      1      0      0         19    19
    20      0      0      0         20    20
    21      1     38      1         20    21
    22      0     38      2         20    21
    23      1      0      0         23    23
    24      4      0      0         24    24
    25      4      0      0         25    25
    26      2      0      0         26    26
    27      3      0      0         27    27
```

I already checked various Pandas functions like `df['Final'] = df['Substract'].loc[lambda x: x > df['Substract'].duplicated()]` or `apply(lambda)` but I get an error; I know that it can be done with Pandas functions, but I can't find how to achieve it. If anyone can help me, I'll be very grateful. Regards.

Comment: Shouldn't row 16, 17 and 18 all be 15?

Comment: Thanks a lot @VivekKalyanarangan No, n the case of the index 15 to 18 there it is consecutive and it should not apply that, because it goes according to the IdPar column.

Comment: In the case of the index 15 to 18, there is a consecutive number from 14 to 15 and it should not apply that, if I achieved to explain?

Comment: It lacks a validation of whether it is consecutive or not, this can be seen in the indexes from 15 to 18, where the 15 is consecutive of the index 16 and then it should not add anything and leave that column or those values as they are in the column Subs; but what is the best way to use a condition for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)-

```
df['Substract'] + (df['Substract'].shift() == df['Substract'])
```

OR (thanks to @SeaBean)

```
df['Substract'] + (df['Substract'].diff() == 0)
```

**Output**

```
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      6
8      6
9      6
10     6
11    11
12    12
13    13
14    13
15    14
16    15
17    15
18    15
19    19
20    20
21    21
22    21
23    23
24    24
25    25
26    26
27    27
Name: Substract, dtype: int64
```

Comment: You can also use `df['Substract'] + (df['Substract'].diff() == 0)` to simplify the code.

Comment: Thanks to both, a validation or condition is missing. This can be seen in the indexes from 15 to 18, where the 15 is consecutive of the index 16 in the column Final and then it should not add anything and leave that column or those values as they are in the Subs column; I'm testing with `If df ['IdPar'] == 0:` and I get an error, but what is the best way to use a condition for that?

Comment: I keep checking and I don't think the condition is whether it is consecutive or not, but this can be seen when painting the dataframe in the console, it is seen in the index 15 to 18 they are not repeated, but it starts with 14 and continues with 15; this is related to the IdPar column and could be, as long as IdPar! = 0 it doesn't apply the solution you gave me: df ['Substract'] + (df ['Substract']. diff () == 0) or something so... but how do I interpret that?

Comment: I found how to do it with loc[], I added this to my code:
`df['Final'] = df['Subtract']`
`df.loc df['IdPar'] != 0, 'Final'] = df['Subtract'] + (df['Subtract']. diff() == 0)`
But I still get the same as you do: index: [....15,16,17,18...] and Final column: [...14,15,15,15...]